# error using foreign data wrapper

Tags: python, postgresql, elasticsearch, foreign-data-wrapper

I am trying to use foreign data wrapper, added the server, triggers and other prerequisites, however when i try to insert the entry, i get the below error.

```
ERROR:  INDEX for /test/media/2 and document {'description': 
u'dffffff', 'tags': u'{aa,ss}', 'title': u'ddd', 'score': None, 
'query': None} failed: 
ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7f6df9b82e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] 
Name or service not known) caused by: 
NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7f6df9b82e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] 
Name or service not known)
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO media_es
          (
              id,
              title,
              description,
              tags
          )
      VALUES
          (
              NEW.id,
              NEW.title,
              NEW.description,
              NEW.tags
          )"
PL/pgSQL function index_media() line 3 at SQL statement
********** Error **********
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was with the host to connect to elastic search.
My host and port was incorrectly installed into postgresql